# How to define a TypeScript type with a variable number of generics

Tags: typescript

I'm attempting to make an `emit` function that can accept multiple arguments. Furthermore, the 2nd argument and beyond will be validated by TypeScript based on the 1st argument (the event).

I have the code below as a starting point, but it obviously doesn't work as intended.

```js
type CallbackFunc<T extends any[]> = (...args: T) => void;
interface TrackablePlayerEventMap {
    'play:other': CallbackFunc<['audio' | 'video']>;
    error: CallbackFunc<[Error, Record<string, unknown>]>;
}

const eventHandlers: Partial<TrackablePlayerEventMap> = {};

function on<K extends keyof TrackablePlayerEventMap>(event: K, callback: TrackablePlayerEventMap[K]) {
}

function emit<K extends keyof TrackablePlayerEventMap>(event: K, ...args: TrackablePlayerEventMap[K]) {
    const handler = eventHandlers[event];

    handler(...args);
}

on('error', (e, metadata) => {
    console.log(e, metadata)
});
on('play:other', x => {
    console.log(x);
});

// This should be valid
emit('error', new Error('Ouch'), { count: 5 });

// This should be invalid
emit('error', 123, 456);
```

Comment: It's not 100% clear what your main question is.  I *presume* it's "how can I write this" and not "why is my version not working"?   So my answer will focus on the former and not the latter ... and can we forget `on()` entirely?  Seems irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to write `handler(...args)` once inside the body of `emit()` and have it compile with no errors, you need to make use of the technique introduced in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) as a fix for an issue I've called "correlated unions", as mentioned in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

The first step is to come up with a type that maps your `event` values to the parameters list (the `args` array). It's *like* your `TrackablePlayerEventMap` type, but the properties are just parameter tuple types and not function types:

```
interface TPEventParamsMap {
    'play:other': ['audio' | 'video'],
    error: [Error, Record<string, unknown>];
}
```

Then we give `eventHandlers` type a type written explicitly in terms of `TPEventParamsMap`:

```
const eventHandlers: {
    [K in keyof TPEventParamsMap]?: CallbackFunc<TPEventParamsMap[K]>
} = {};
```

Conceptually that's the exact same as your `Partial<TrackablePlayerEventMap>` type, but this one is explicitly written as a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) on `TPEventParamsMap`, which the compiler can use to keep track of the correlation between the `event` type (of type `K`) and the parameters to the event handler function (of type  `TPEventParamsMap[K]`).

Continuing:

```
function emit<K extends keyof TPEventParamsMap>(
    event: K,
    ...args: TPEventParamsMap[K]
) {
    const handler = eventHandlers[event];
    handler?.(...args); // okay
}
```

That compiles with no error.  Note that since `eventHandlers` is `Partial` it might not have a value at key `event`, so we are using [the optional chaining operator (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to call the function only if it exists.

And `emit()` behaves as desired from the caller's side too:

```
emit('error', new Error('Ouch'), { count: 5 }); // okay
emit('error', 123, 456); // error, 123 is not an Error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNYDECuA7NAHgBUoIAPYCPAEwGco48QBtAXQD4oBeKACgB0QuACcA5nQBcUYgEoeXAG4B7AJY0A3ACgtqvFREAzdNGIAFAKKLqwM6LgBbOgFk4YKAG8tUH1ADkYAhwIJLKwAAWECJ+0ix+cDg0qsp+UAA+-orqEClsADTevlEiyiKxFiIlInlQAEoQaKU0hHTAInpiNfgYeMoA7ngcbNoAvjqNeK1k1voAEkw0CFFSnoU+LADSUHpQGBAgyoYyljO29k6uYGwA-NLwSKiYuAQkJzZ2Io4ubpucWiM8TwjbQ6Qz4NDAZJ4MgOVTAQhbChUWgMPYHI7mKzvc7fMAcPhraY2aQbAq+KBCASiCTSTGnD5fS6-LTyLzkiZTcILJYiQEQU7zWg8ugsfk2YaErlCqLXASCYTiOiyUY6CCw4B8PzFUp+Gp4CB9KAVKqagDyODQ4T8shqHigjXwwGkAFYoCNlVAAPSeqDKDDBLRquGa7XRGoARgATABmGoAFmdADYPd6yJVShGY9sGL1gIxocbSjpi2CCJDlNCKwiyJRqPRdvtDscsfoGRc3PjCWL9CSyb40IgUOgMHdB49sODXi2zp922BfhwWZ43ToKyH02H+BAag4IMA4DQ4Pv5NwuGz+xW6MolgIEMoxHxt1Bd-vD8f-h6tGuAkEQmFIpu5AKKs7KXteEC3vefDkMqH7aEAA)

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you so much! Now that I'm looking at the code, it seems obvious, but with TypeScript I'm often not breaking things down enough into smaller parts like you have.

Comment: Just one more thing: If I add `eventHandlers[event] = callback;` into the `on()` function, I get a type error. I'm not really sure how to address that one.

Comment: To lead the compiler through that you need to write `eventHandlers`'s type as a distributive object type and then upcast it. Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZ479w).  I assume this is out of scope of the original question as asked and if you want more explanation you should ask a new question (which I might or might not get to)

Comment: That helps, thanks! That's where TS reaches a level of complexity that's way beyond me, and I usually just slap a `@ts-ignore` on it and call it a day.